# Service Fabric : Restore to a particular version?

Tags: c#, azure, sass, backup, azure-service-fabric

I have Backup and Restore implemented with service fabric.
My backups go into folders on azure with time stamp and the service name.

At the moment I just search the latest backup, but what if I want to restore to an older version?

I invoke the data loss using

```
 await fabricClient.TestManager.StartPartitionDataLossAsync(operationId, partitionSelector, DataLossMode.FullDataLoss);
```

This triggers the data loss here.

```
protected override async Task<bool> OnDataLossAsync(RestoreContext restoreCtx, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await this.SetupBackupManager(null);

    try
    {
        string backupFolder = await this.backupManager.RestoreLatestBackupToTempLocation(cancellationToken);

        RestoreDescription restoreRescription = new RestoreDescription(backupFolder, RestorePolicy.Force);

        await restoreCtx.RestoreAsync(restoreRescription, cancellationToken);

        DirectoryInfo tempRestoreDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(backupFolder);
        tempRestoreDirectory.Delete(true);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I have my code in my backup manager to handle it, but I can't think/find a way to pass anything to OnDataLossAsync.

RestoreLatestBackupToTempLocation finds the latest backup.

Answer (score 0):

You could store that information outside of the cluster, like in [Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables), and read it from there during restore.

edit:
I've been working on an [open source project](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.BackupRestore) that will help make this simpler. Feedback & contributions welcome.